# sed with a comment in macOS, it gives me an error

Tags: bash, sed

I can't find any resources about this issue.

macOS and ubuntu both give me the same result like below.

```sh
>>> seq 10 | sed '
3p
6d
'
1
2
3
3
4
5
7
8
9
10
```

but when I insert the comment, sed in macOS gives me the error.

```sh
>>> seq 10 | sed '
3p  # print 3rd line
6d  # print 6th line
'
sed: 2: "
3p  # print 3rd line
6 ...": extra characters at the end of p command
```

is a comment not supported in macOS? or did I some mistake?
please let me know, thank you.

Comment: the original question title was "sed comment not working in macOS". but StackOverflow rejected it repeatedly :(

Comment: As per [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands) - `If you are concerned about portability, be aware that some implementations of sed (which are not POSIX conforming) may only support a single one-line comment, and then only when the very first character of the script is a #.`

Comment: @Sundeep I want to select your answer but I can't because it's a comment. how can I make this question be [solved]? should I delete this question?

Comment: @0xF4D3C0D3 wait for some time, I don't know about macOS, there may be some other reason for this.. I don't think you should delete the question.. also, could you check what happens if you have comment on its own line, for ex `# print 3rd line` then on next line `3p` and next line `# print 6th line` and next line `6d` etc

Comment: @Sundeep I think you're right because it works perfectly when comments have its own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you use sed for more than s/old/new/ you're using the wrong tool and probably using non-portable constructs. Just use awk for portability, clarity, efficiency, robustness, etc. This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '
NR == 3 { print }
NR == 6 { print }
{ print }
'
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
9
10
```

No comments required because **the code is clear**. You can add comments if you like of course:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '
NR == 3 { print }       # print 3rd line
NR == 6 { print }       # print 6th line
{ print }               # print all lines
'
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
9
10
```

or if you wanted to delete instead of print the 6th line:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '
NR == 3 { print }       # print 3rd line
NR == 6 { next }        # delete 6th line
{ print }               # print all lines
'
1
2
3
3
4
5
7
8
9
10
```

and you can make the code a bit less clear by relying on default behavior if you prefer brevity:

```
# seq 10 | awk '
NR == 3                 # print 3rd line
NR == 6                 # print 6th line
1                       # print all lines
'
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
9
10

$ seq 10 | awk '
NR == 3       # print 3rd line
NR != 6       # print all lines except the 6th
'
1
2
3
3
4
5
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: you gave me a new point of view about text manipulation. I'm gonna try awk as well. for now, I wanna understand the sed first. btw tysm :)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf is this what you said? it's written by Arnold tho, I don't know it' ok that I can get this book for free. and here is where It came from https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/

Comment: That's the PDF of the book which Arnold made available for us to refer to for free for our convenience but people buying the book is the only way he gets any money for writing the book, providing that document online and actually providing/maintaining the tool GNU awk so I always encourage everyone to buy the book.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it later. or buy it if it catch my fancy, actually I'm getting tired of less-portability(BSD vs GNU vs ...), less-readability(like variable name as a b c foo bar), gotcha in sed (don't take offence please)

Comment: That book covers all awks and additionally tells you about GNU-specific functionality so it's got everything.